# How to assign name to R character object

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
inde.vars <- structure(list(Group = c("CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR", 
"CUR", "CUR", "CUR", "CUR"), Subject = c("0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Condition = c("L1", "L1", "L1", 
"L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L3", "L4"), Trial = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L)), row.names = c(1L, 68L, 76L, 
151L, 226L, 301L, 376L, 451L, 464L, 539L), class = "data.frame")

classes.group <- inde.vars[,1]
```

What do I need to do to assign object name or some identifier, for example, "Group" for character object `classes.group` so I get someting like:

```
names(classes.group)
"Group"
```

Comment: You can have an attribute or use `setNames`.  Here the `names` wouldn't work because the length of 'classes.group' is the number of rows of 'inde.vars'  For a vecttor, if you name it, it should be for the entire length.  You could have an attribute assigned

Comment: @akrun Do I need to name all elements? Example shows `setNames( 1:3, c("foo", "bar", "baz") )` I only want to name it keeping the object as character.

Comment: I would assign with an attribute i.e. `attr(classes.group, 'name') <- 'Group'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need an attribute then we can have

```
attr(classes.group, 'name') <- 'Group'
classes.group
#[1] "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR"
#attr(,"name")
#[1] "Group"
```

We can extract with `attributes` or `attr`

```
attr(classes.group, 'name')
#[1] "Group"
```

---

The issue with having a `named` `vector` when the `vector` `length` is greater than 1 is we need to `rep`licate the value 'Group' to the entire `length`

Comment: this better approach than my answer

Answer (score 1):

use names to assign a name to object. in general

```
names(object)<-c("ObjectDesiredName1","ObjectDesiredName2",..)
```

for your case:

```
names(classes.group)<-"Group" or
names(classes.group)<-c("Group")
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for me because you see here: `> classes.group
Group  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
"CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" "CUR" `

Comment: I want to keep classes.group as character.

Comment: Can use this :names(classes.group)<-rep("Group",length(classes.group))